# ESP32 with CP2102 - PC does not recognize the controller

Tags: microcontroller, pcb, serial, esp32, cp2102

The controller that I made does not show up in the device manager when connected to PC. I checked the drivers and the problem is not there. I already found (and corrected on the schematic) one mistake - the RST# pin was not connected to the VDD pin. I was wondering if there are any other possible issues with my design.

[image]

[image]

**UPDATE:**

The multimeter shows the proper voltages across all the major pins/components with no short circuits. As one of the comments mentioned, the thermal pad on CP2102 should be grounded. I will somehow try to fix the mentioned issues and report back!

Comment: Over that short length it's probably not causing you that much trouble right now, but you could try to improve your USB D+ & D- routing. Keep them together as a pair, and avoid stubs like the one on D+ leading to the TVS. A nice ground-plane pour certainly wouldn't hurt either.

Comment: The [CP2102 datasheet](https://www.silabs.com/documents/public/data-sheets/CP2102-9.pdf) specifies on page 12 that the thermal pad (EP on your schematic) should be grounded.

Comment: Maybe the problem is not in the schematics or PCB layout? Have you done any checks if the parts are mounted on PCB in correct orientation, with no short circuits, or missing parts? Have you done any measurements with multimeter or scope to see what the problem might be?

Comment: @brhans thanks for mentioning it! I completely missed that :(

Comment: @Justme no short circuits, voltages across the components are correct.

Comment: Your VDD input to the CP2102 has no 3.3V connected, only a decoupling cap and Vbus should probably be connected over a voltage divider

Comment: @HansPeterLoft That is OK, VDD is a 3.3V output from the internal regularor when REGIN is fed with 5V. And VBUS does not need voltage divider when bus powered. It would if VBUS can be present without other supplies.